# How to get selected value in option id value in drupal form api

Tags: forms

Hi hello please help how to get dynamically selected option id value (i.e #options=>0=>'bala',1=>'kumar')

for example (1001->india,1002->usa) like that stored in select option value (india, usa like that) , but i want to fetch the id value(1001, 1002) of selected value of id value from option? that value to be store in $key variable, please help me

```
$query_state=db_select('state', 's');
$query_state->fields('s',array('State_code','State_name'));
$query_state->orderBy('State_name','ASC');
$state_results = $query_state->execute();
$options_state = array();

foreach($state_results as $state_record) {
  $options_state[$state_record->State_name]=t($state_record->State_code);
}

$form['state1']= array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('State'),
  '#options' =>$options_state,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => '_ajaxfunction',
    'wrapper' => 'divaroundseconddropdown'
  ),
);

// here values are popup in select option component but corresponding value of state in city select option not visible 


 $key = !empty($form_state['values']['state1']) ? $form_state['values']['state1'] : 1;



$query_city=db_select('city', 'c');
$query_city->fields('c',array('District_Code','District_Name','State_Code'));
$query_city->condition('State_Code',$key,'=');

$query_city->orderBy('District_Name','ASC');
$city_results = $query_city->execute();
$options_city = array();


foreach ($city_results as $city_record) {
  $options_city[$city_record->District_Code]=t($city_record->District_Name);
}

$form['city']= array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('District'),
  '#options' => $options_city,
  '#prefix' => '<div id="divaroundseconddropdown">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#states'=>array(
    'visible'=>array(
      ':input[name="state1"]' => array(
          'value' => $options_state,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


function _ajaxfunction($form, $form_state) { 
  return $form['city'];
}
```

Comment: In the ajax callback function "_ajaxfunction" make sure that you are taking the reference of $form_state variable

Comment: yes i have given function _ajaxfunction($form, $form_state) 
{ 
return $form['city']; 
}

Comment: $key = !empty($form_state['values']['state1']) ? $form_state['values']['state1'] : 1;

where you are doing this? in the ajax callback function?

Comment: $form['state1']= array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('State'),
  '#options' =>$options_state,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => '_ajaxfunction',
    'wrapper' => 'divaroundseconddropdown'
  ),
);


 $key = !empty($form_state['values']['state1']) ? $form_state['values']['state1'] : 1;

Comment: you cannot fetch the value of a form element just after creating the form element. You have to move the code for $key to the ajax callback function

Comment: can u give me email id, i will forward whole source code to u, please give me the suggestion sir, i am new to drupal

Comment: better post the whole code in this question :)

Comment: i have posted please help me sir how to do

Comment: A user selects a certain state, on selecting state an option for setting city will appear. If user unselects state then city setting will not be visible, on selecting state again city will be visible again. Are you trying to implement this?

Comment: yes exactly sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
function YOUR_FUNCTION_THAT_DISPLAYS_FORM(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $query_state=db_select('state', 's');
  $query_state->fields('s',array('State_code','State_name'));
  $query_state->orderBy('State_name','ASC');
  $state_results = $query_state->execute();

  $options_state = array();

  // Using fetchAll() you can iterate through a result set.
  while ($state_record = $state_results->fetchAll()) {
    // You want state code as key, not state name as key.
    $options_state[$state_record->State_code]=t($state_record->State_name);
  }

  // State form element.
  $form['state1']= array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('State'),
    '#options' =>$options_state,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_ajaxfunction',
      'wrapper' => 'divaroundseconddropdown'
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );

  // City wrapper form element.
  $form['city_element_wrapper'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="divaroundseconddropdown">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  return $form;
}




// AJAX callback function.
function _ajaxfunction(&$form, &$form_state) { 
  $key = !empty($form_state['values']['state1']) ? $form_state['values']['state1'] : 1;

  $query_city=db_select('city', 'c');
  $query_city->fields('c',array('District_Code','District_Name','State_Code'));
  $query_city->condition('State_Code', $key, '=');

  $query_city->orderBy('District_Name','ASC');
  $city_results = $query_city->execute();
  $options_city = array();


  while ($city_record = $city_results->fetchAll()) {
    // This is correct.
    $options_city[$city_record->District_Code]=t($city_record->District_Name);
  }

  // Render city setting.
  $form['city_element_wrapper']['city']= array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('District'),
    '#options' => $options_city,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

  return $form['city_element_wrapper'];
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: after declare this line the concept is working nice, thank u              very much sir     return $form['city_element_wrapper'];

Comment: I have edited the answer. Glad this helped you :)

Comment: but I cant able to store the value of city_element_wrapper into variable while submitting the form (for example function form_test_custom_form_submit($form, $form_state) { $data1 = $form_state['values']['city_element_wrapper']['city']; }) data not storing into $data1. please help me